# How to identify and send messages to application from Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel module that sends and receives internet packets and I'm using Generic Netlink to communicate between Kernel and Userspace.

When the application wants to send an internet message (doesn't matter what the protocol is), I can send it to the Kernel with no problems via one of the functions I defined in my generic netlink family and the module sends it through the wire. All is fine.

But when the module receives a packet, how can I reach the appropriate process to deliver the message? My trouble is not in identifying the correct process: that is done via custom protocols (e.g. IP tables); but it consists in what information should I store to notify the correct process?

So far I keep only the `portid` of the process (because it initiates the communication) and I have been trying to use the function `genlmsg_unicast()`, but it was altered in a Kernel version of 2009 in such a way that it requires an additional parameter (besides `skb *buffer` and `portid`): a pointer to a struct net. None of the tutorials I have found addresses this issue.

I tried using `&init_net` as the new parameter, but the computer just freezes and I have to restart it through the power button.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you not getting/making a socket? You should listen for a connection with your driver or user space process and connect with the other. Once established the socket should have all the information to pass messages between them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @charlesw. I discovered what the problem was. I will answer my own question, so people know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered what was causing the issue:
It turned out that I was freeing the buffer at the end of the function. #facepalm

I shouldn't be doing so, because the buffer gets queued and it waits there until it is actually delivered. So it is not the caller's reponsability to free the buffer, if the function `genlmsg_unicast()` succeeds.

Now it works with `&init_net`.